# Flask-SQLAlchemy error: "current transaction is aborted"

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I've been trying to translate a raw SQL Query into a SQLAlchemy query. The raw SQL i first wrote is the following:

```
SELECT COUNT("Shows".id), "Venue".name, "Venue".city, "Venue".state FROM "Venue" JOIN "Shows" ON "Venue".id="Shows".venue_id GROUP BY("Venue".name,"Venue".city,"Venue".state) ORDER BY COUNT("Shows".id)
```

This is my translation to SQLAlchemy:

```
Venue.query.with_entities(func.count(Shows.id),Venue.name, Venue.city, Venue.state).join(Shows).group_by(Venue.name, Venue.city, Venue.state)
```

That doesn't work, i get an error message, including the raw SQL query that was produced by SQLAlchemy:

```
SELECT count("Shows".id) AS count_1, "Venue".name AS "Venue_name", "Venue".city AS "Venue_city", "Venue".state AS "Venue_state" 
FROM "Venue" JOIN "Shows" ON "Venue".id = "Shows".venue_id GROUP BY "Venue".name, "Venue".city, "Venue".state
```

This is the error message i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2768, in all
    return self._iter().all()
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2903, in _iter
    result = self.session.execute(
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1712, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1631, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1498, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1862, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2043, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/reinmar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction) current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

To my surprise, when using that query directly within the PSQL Tool, it works exactly the way i want.

This behavior doesn't make sense to me, what is wrong?

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the complete stack trace including the actual error message(s) you receive.

Comment: Now it works after i  restarted the whole app and python3. Maybe it's about the session?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?